How extract partial data from one sheet to another sheet in Google Sheets
So I have to sheets, Expenses and Tax Expenses Overview. The Expenses sheet has it's data filled via a Google form where I track date of purchase, the category it fits, whether it's tax deductible, etc. The "Is this tax deductible" column filled with "Yes" or "No" data. I want to take all the cells that have "Yes" and take all the data from those rows and populate the Tax Expenses Overview sheet with it.
The Tax Expenses Overview sheet would sort this data by category and date (Specifically month by month) and display the totals for each category for each month.
I'm struggling to figure out a formula to do this. Any help would be appreciated.
In the pictures you can see how the data is displayed in the Expenses sheet and how I'd like to display them in the Tax Expenses Overview sheet.
For example, cell B2 in Tax Expenses Overview should display £168 (The sum of two expenses that are tax deductible from the same month, £99 and £69)
This is the Expenses Sheet filled with the data from the Google form
This is the Tax Expenses Overview sheet with a failed formula that I have edited from a different sheet
UPDATE!!
I have implemented to formula from the comment and edited it slightly (maybe incorrectly), and it doesn't seem to bring data over for other categories.
Here's the sheet with the formula added. Cell E5 should have £14
Expenses Sheet with new data for testing.


Instead of images, add data samples as a table. You might use a formula or a sheet add-on, among other means, to format the data correctly. Please remember that data samples and formulas should be a [mcve]. 2. Whenever possible, avoid adding "updates" based on the answers that you got. If the answer is unclear, add a comment to the respective answer. If you need to make a follow-up question, post it as a new question.



You may try:
=sumifs(Expenses!F:F,Expenses!E:E,B1,Expenses!D:D,"Yes",index(eomonth(Expenses!B:B,)),eomonth(A2,))


Hey! Thanks for this. I added the code (And slightly adjusted it:
'=sumifs(Expenses!$F:$F,Expenses!$E:$E,$B2,Expenses!$D:$D,"Yes",index(eomonth(Expenses!$B:$B,)),eomonth(C$2,))'
However this doesn't seem to correctly bring the data over for other categories.
I'll add the updated images into the original post

Share a test sheet. Can't keep winging the formula based on just the screenshots

Here's the link for you
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sk5UO-LLM6bnCNfZ0SjxCf-rfprZT49r9Y9JXNhTyzY/edit?usp=sharing

the sheet has restricted access
